# last_accessed time in beaker session always None, but _accessed_time is changing

Tags: python, mod-wsgi, wsgi, beaker

I'm using `beakers WSGI SessionMiddleware` to manage a session between browser and application.
I am trying to differentiate between when a session is first accessed against any further requests.

Fom the docs it appears there are two useful values made available in the WSGI environment,
`["beaker.session"].last_accessed`  and `["beaker.session"]["_accessed_time"]`

However,  on repeated requests `["beaker.session"].last_accessed` is always returning `None`, while the timestamp value in `["beaker.session"]["_accessed_time"]` can be seen to be increasing with each request.

Each request performs a `["beaker.session"].save()` - I have tried various combinations of setting `auto=True` in the session, and using `.save() / .persist()`,   but no joy :  `.last_accessed` is always `None`.

I am not using the session to actually persist any data, only to manage the creation of and pass through the `session.id`. ( I am using a session type of 'cookie' )

Answer (score 1):

It turns out this behaviour is down to multiprocessing via apache.

It was resolved by using an external store to manage tracking when the session ID is first seen, and maintaining my own 'last_accessed_time' etc.